# Linq to fill nested objects with pivot

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two tables as below

```
Person{
    int id;
    string name;
}
PersonAddresses{
    int id;
    string AddressType;
    string City;
    string State;
}
```

Here AddressType specifies "BusinessAddress","HomeAddress" etc.
I want to Get the result as below.

```
class PersonData{
    int id;
    string Name;
    Address BusinessAddress;
    Address HomeAddress;
    ...
}
class Address{
    string City;
    string State;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this using LINQ without multiple selects?

Comment: what kind of linq you are using? entity framework? linq to sql?

Comment: I am using linq to entity framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Group join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins) combined with sub-selects to get Home and Business addresses from a group:

```
var query =
    from person in Persons
    join address in PersonAddresses
    on person.id equals address.id into personData
    select new PersonData()
    {
        id = person.id,
        Name = person.name,
        HomeAddress = (
            from data in personData
            where data.AddressType == "HomeAddress"
            select new Address()
            {
                City = data.City,
                State = data.State
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
        BusinessAddress = (
            from data in personData
            where data.AddressType == "BusinessAddress"
            select new Address()
            {
                City = data.City,
                State = data.State
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
    };
```

This runs as single SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
    [Limit1].[id] AS [id1], 
    [Limit1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Limit1].[State] AS [State], 
    [Limit2].[id] AS [id2], 
    [Limit2].[City] AS [City1], 
    [Limit2].[State] AS [State1]
    FROM   [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent2].[id] AS [id], 
        [Extent2].[City] AS [City], 
        [Extent2].[State] AS [State]
        FROM [dbo].[PersonAddresses] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[id] = [Extent2].[id]) AND (N'HomeAddress' = [Extent2].[AddressType]) ) AS [Limit1]
    OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
        [Extent3].[id] AS [id], 
        [Extent3].[City] AS [City], 
        [Extent3].[State] AS [State]
        FROM [dbo].[PersonAddresses] AS [Extent3]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[id] = [Extent3].[id]) AND (N'BusinessAddress' = [Extent3].[AddressType]) ) AS [Limit2]
```

Comment: perfect. Earlier I tried this but all I missed is the select "into". Thanks

Comment: @Ňuf what is the real difference from my answer?

Comment: @AlexButenko: My code does only one grouping (as opposed to two groupings and two joins), which should perform better with LINQ to Objects. With entity framework, your code produces SQL query with two additional (and superfluous) `LEFT JOIN`s (though SQL server might be abe to optimize these out, I didn't try). My code also seems to be considerably shorter.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest query I can come up with is like this

```
// by doing groupby and select you choose only one address of the type,
// if a person has many.
// If you can be sure that each person has only one address of each type
// then you can simplify these queries a little bit.
IQueryable<PersonAddresses> homeAddresses = from address in addresses
                                            where address.AddressType == "HomeAddress"
                                            group address by address.id into g
                                            select g.First();

IQueryable<PersonAddresses> businessAddresses = from address in addresses
                                                where address.AddressType == "BusinessAddress"
                                                group address by address.id into g
                                                select g.First();
IQueryable<PersonData> data = from person in persons
                              join tmp1 in homeAddresses on person.id equals tmp1.id into ha
                              join tmp2 in businessAddresses on person.id equals tmp2.id into ba
                              from homeAddress in ha.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              from businessAddress in ba.DefaultIfEmpty()
                              select new PersonData {
                                id = person.id,
                                Name = person.name,
                                HomeAddress = homeAddress == null
                                  ? null
                                  : new Address {
                                    City = homeAddress.City,
                                    State = homeAddress.State
                                  },
                                BusinessAddress = businessAddress == null
                                  ? null
                                  : new Address {
                                    City = businessAddress.City,
                                    State = businessAddress.State
                                  },
                              };
```

You can get the resulting sql query like this:

```
  string sql = ((System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery) data).ToTraceString();
```

You can simplify here and there, but it will have less sense, because you usually cannot completely expect your data to be correct - some list have duplicates, some values are missing, so my query covers corner cases.

Comment: thanks @Alex Butenko This is a nice idea but the problem is that it will convert to 3 sql queries (I have several sub objects like address). Is there any way to reduce number of queries?

Comment: @aditya If you are using entity framework, I don't think it will be 3 queries. I think I will be 1

Comment: we are selecting addresses one time and then the person details another time right? how to see the generated query?

Comment: @aditya see my edit. IQueryable does not query anything from the database immediately. It is just and expression, until you start to enumerate it. You don't need to think about inlining each statement together, entity framework will do it for you.